# Sending values to text box during run time

Tags: c#, winforms

I am running a console application. I am having a textbox in a form. I need to calculate number of messages read in last five minutes in another class and display the value in textbox. When I run the code I can able to see the textbox.text value correctly. But in UI I can't see the value is displayed in the textbox. But I can able to edit the textbox manually during runtime.

Here is my code:

**In codebehind**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMsgs; i++)
{
    if (addDateTime.AddMinutes(2).Minute==DateTime.Now.Minute)
    {
        //FilesProcessedInFiveMinutes();
        //Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FiveMinutesMessage));
        //thread1.Start();
        WebSphereUI webSphereUi = new WebSphereUI();
        webSphereUi.count(fiveMinutesCount);
        addDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
    fiveMinutesCount = fiveMinutesCount + 1;
}
```

**In form.cs**

```
public void count(int countValue)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    txtLastFiveMins.Focus();
    txtLastFiveMins.Text = countValue.ToString();
    txtLastFiveMins.Refresh();
    txtLastFiveMins.Show();
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(2000);
}
```

Comment: You have a console window *and* a form? Why?

Comment: I need to calculate total number of messages processed in last five minutes. Since I need to connect to queue, I have separated those operations in a console. initially I had a console window. then I have added a form to it. Is that cause any problem?

Comment: I really don't understand why that justifies having both. Generally, an application is either a Windows Forms application *or* a Console application, not both. Making them work together can be rather difficult, and there's just little point. You can create two forms to display output if you need to.

Comment: I have now created separate windows application and added other class files and connected to the queue. All are working fine as before. But still value is not displaying in the UI textbox while running. But while debugging, I can able to see the value is assigned to textbox.text. Why it cannot be able display on the textbox? So frustrating.

Comment: Are you sure that your count method is called? You only need txtLastFiveMins.Text = countValue.ToString();

Comment: As a quick test, what happens if you add Application.DoEvents() after setting the text value of the textbox? note that this is not the solution but a diagnostic tool.

Comment: @EwaldStieger count method is getting called and correct value for  txtLastFiveMins.Text is getting assigned. But it is not getting displayed. I just tried other possible ways. Yes,  txtLastFiveMins.Text = countValue.ToString(); is enough for me. Though, my problem is not getting fixed.

Comment: @JamesB Application.DoEvents() is also not working for me. Still same problem exists.

Comment: What is the base class of WebSphereUI? Is that a class for IPC or is that the form?

Comment: Please post the code section that calls count. Also, try it on a clean form - drop a textbox and test your count method.

Comment: It is there inside the if condition itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a new form every time you enter the if statement. This line is creating a new `WebSphereUI` form:

```
    WebSphereUI webSphereUi = new WebSphereUI();
```

Then, you call the `count` method on it:

```
    webSphereUi.count(fiveMinutesCount);
```

But then you you continue on, without showing this form. If you add:

```
    webSphereUi.Show();
```

Then you might see the form appear on the screen, displaying the value as expected. However, this is going to show a new form every time the if statement is executed. You could reuse the same form by declaring it elsewhere, and using it in the loop:

```
class yourClass
{

    WebSphereUI webSphereUi = new WebSphereUI();

    ...

    private void yourFunction()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMsgs; i++)
        {
            if (addDateTime.AddMinutes(2).Minute==DateTime.Now.Minute)
            {
                webSphereUi.count(fiveMinutesCount);
                webSphereUi.Show();
                addDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
            fiveMinutesCount = fiveMinutesCount + 1;
        }
    }

}
```